# How to get the Entity-SQL command text by LINQ query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, code-first, entity-sql

It's an exercise of EF code-first. There's a simple method. I want to get the Entity SQL command text generated by object services.

(*MyDbContext* is derived form *DbContext*. *Person* is a POCO class.)

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var query = context.Set<Person>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Age == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(query.Name);


    var objquery = query as ObjectQuery;
    if (objquery != null)
        Console.WriteLine(objquery.CommandText);
}
```

I used to get native SQL command text by `ObjectQuery.TraceString` in LINQ to Entity. Now, what I need is Entity-SQL statement, **NOT** native SQL statement.

But, I can't cast the query from `IQueryable<Person>` to `ObjectQuery` or `ObjectQuery<Person>`.
I tried to get members of `DbQuery` by reflection. It seems that `DbQuery` hasn't any property about command text or trace string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for what you want is using Dynamic Linq.  The library (part of the [Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx)) includes many IQueryable extensions that return Linq.DataQuery objects.  Once you consume the DataQuery you'll have the expected object.

```
var testQuery =
    db.Cases.
    Where("KeyID > 1").
    Take(1);

foreach (var r in testQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Then, you can check against your query as such.

```
testQuery.Expression
testQuery.Provider
```

These will give you:

```
{Table(Case).Where( => (.Keyid > 1)).Take(1)} 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression {System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression}
```

-and-

```
{SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Keyid], [t0].[FileNo], [t0].[MatterType], [t0].[LoanNo], [t0].[Investor], [t0].[LoanType], [t0].[Client], [t0].[ClientFileNo], [t0].[ClientStatus], [t0].[Mortgagor], [t0].[County], [t0].[PropertyStreet1], [t0].[PropertyStreet2], [t0].[PropertyCity], [t0].[PropertyState], [t0].[PropertyZipcode], [t0].[Status], [t0].[BoxNo], [t0].[InsurerLoanno], [t0].[InvestorLoanno], [t0].[insurer_name_id], [t0].[OldSystemKey], [t0].[FinalBilling], [t0].[HoldBilling], [t0].[LastModified], [t0].[PiggyLoanNo], [t0].[CurrComentID], [t0].[LockEFILE], [t0].[MSJAmount], [t0].[Created], [t0].[Locked], [t0].[FinalBillingDate], [t0].[HoldBillingDate], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[Stage], [t0].[PriorStage], [t0].[DefendantUpdated], [t0].[VestingCode], [t0].[FileSource], [t0].[SubVestingCode], [t0].[AttorneyAssigment], [t0].[VoluntarySurrender], [t0].[FNMARisk], [t0].[Source], [t0].[REO_ID], [t0].[WTI_ID], [t0].[CaseDismissed], [t0].[REO_CompanyID], [t0].[SubMattertype], [t0].[VendorCode], [t0].[SubType]
FROM [dbo].[Cases] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Keyid] > @p0}
System.Linq.IQueryProvider {System.Data.Linq.DataQuery<CMSDEVMapping.Case>}
```

You can also verify your type in the loop:

```
r.GetType() {Name = "Case" FullName = "CMSDEVMapping.Case"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

Comment: Get it. Now I think I should write the query with query builder method.  Thank you.

Comment: And I think the SQL statement above is native SQL. I'll try the other way.